# hpux: i want to see print queue jobs

Tags: printing, hp-ux, lpq

On all unix systems I use simply

```
lpq
```

But on hpux didn't exist and i can install only the lpq of cups.
Using the old sysV system(lpsched,etc..) how to see the print
jobs like lpq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably solved,the command to see
jobs is

```
lpstat -t
```